# wp nav menu add 2images to LI left and right side

Tags: css, wordpress

I want to add small image to LI. And LI having background image. So i want to add 2 images to LI left bottom and LI right bottom side.And one more thing that image size is 10*20. So for that what i do ? or how to add div tag so then i will do it easily. I cant't get how to add div tag in wp_nav_menu() . SO please help me out. I am stuck on that.

Comment: add image for all <li> or a specific <li> link ?

Comment: In wordpress LI came from the database by using wp_nav_menu() so how can i add image to LI and i want to add image to LI Tag's bellow. And one more thing i am all ready adding image to LI using CSS but i want to add image bellow background image of LI using DIV . So i stuck on how to add DIV bellow LI.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the `before`, `after`, `link_before` and `link_after` parameters of [`wp_nav_menu()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_nav_menu). Also see the description of the various classes assigned to components of the menu.